# IQueryable<> extension Method

Tags: c#, .net, interface, iqueryable

I have two question that basically refer to the same scope:

1. My specific problem:

   I Have 2 classes: Users, Cars
   I would like to add create extension method which returns IQueryable<>, and use the very same method for both types.
   Is it possible?
2. More general question:
   Using generics I can return any object type. Is it possible to limit the return type to specific types (only my User and Cars classes)?

Thank you

Comment: If you have access to the code, why are you writing extension methods? Surely it would be better just to include the methods in the classes themselves?

Comment: Why do you want to create an extension method than straight class methods?

Comment: @Matt Ellen, could be that he is compiling two DLL's and one of them (containing the extension methods) is optional...  But +1 anyway.

Comment: @Stephen Chung: Yes, I suppose it could be so that an upgrade to functionality is optional.

Answer (score 4):

If Users and Cars share the same ancestor, or implement a common interface, then it is possible to create an extension method that is applicable to both classes.

```
public interface X {}

public class Car : X {}

public class User : X {}

public static class Xtensions
{
   public static Xtension( this X target ) {}
}
```

I cannot see your code, but I wonder if this is not going to be a code-smell ...

But, if you have access to the code / classes, why don't you do it like this:

```
public class X
{
    public virtual void CommonStuff() { }
}

public class Car : X {}

public class User : X {}
```

By making `CommonStuff` virtual, you can override the implementation in any specific case (if necessary).

Generics can be constrained: check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article.

Answer (score 1):

If User and Care are based on the same base class, say Base, then you can do things like:

```
   MyGenericType<T> where T : Base
```

In general, you can specify Base wherever you mean either User or Car.  In extension methods or other methods.  Same.

However, if User and Car do not share the same base class, then you'll have to implement a common interface to tie them together.  For example:

```
class User : IMyInterface...
class Car : IMyInterface...

MyGenericType<T> where T : IMyInterface
```

You have to have *something* to tie the two classes together.  Otherwise, you cannot just specify *any two classes* for the compiler to enforce.